# Bank loan model (spr?)

Tags: generalized-linear-model, modeling, fitting

[image]

I am trying to fit a model investigating the amount of the loan (or a transformation of it) as a function of the the variables income, gender, customer and age.

Fitting a standard linear regression gives poor results (R-squared of only 0.27). Besides, the relationship between income and loan seems quite weird. It has a sort of left-rotated Z-shape (see picture)

Would be appropriate to use a semiparametric model here? If so, how would you model it?

I tried this in R:

```
model <- spm(loan~f(income, basis="trunc.poly")+age+factor(gender)+factor(customer))
```

But this gave poor results (no significant variables).

Anyone has suggestions?

Comment: Could you show us some plots of your data, e.g. how loan amount varies with income for various age buckets and genders?

Comment: Are there multiple loans per customer?  If there's only one loan per customer, including factor(customer) in the model will explain all of the variation (and I presume that's not what you want to do).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have added a graph. Customer is just a categoric variable which can be eather 'No' (when the customer is new to the bank) or 'Yes' (when the customer is not new to the bank)

Comment: This shows a clear mixture of 3 groups (your 3 lines) - there has to be some obvious explanation for the clearly distinct lines. Only a model that distinguishes between those groups would be appropriate - hopefully with interaction effects between loan and group membership (presuming the groups are already labeled).

Comment: The explanatory variables to be used only have two levels, though. It seems impossible to make a model with loan as dependent variable and gender, costumer, age and income as independent.

Comment: Re my earlier comment -- ah, I thought customer was a customer ID. Do you know how to use ggplot2?  Show us a plot with income on the horizontal axis, loan on the vertical, facet_grid(gender ~ is.new.customer), and color by income. If that last sentence makes no sense: try making plots for various subsets, e.g. conditional on gender and is.new.customer.